# Wordpress Multisite and multidomain without parking domains?

Tags: wordpress

This is the scenario:
Domain1.com
Domain2.com

Wordpress MU is installed on Domain1.com.
Domain mapping plugin is installed.
I've followed a few tutorials and I'm pretty sure it would work but the problem is that the nameservers of both Domain1 and Domain2 are pointing to the same server and from Cpanel I manage the dns. The real problem is that I host emails for both on a separate server, so I can't park any of the domains...

Is there any solution to this???

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just point domain2 A record to domain1 in advanced DNS editor